# Hot push website code ala Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, hotdeploy

In [Meteor www.meteor.com](http://www.meteor.com/), every time you save your HTML/Javascript/CSS it will push the changes to the browser and hence **you don't need to refresh the browser manually.

### Is there a way I can do this in standard node.js environment without using meteor ?

What about in PHP / Java environment ?

Comment: Whatever you implement with Node, you'll basically be re-implementing Meteor. So what's the point?

Comment: All i want is the hot-push, while waiting until Meteor supports REST api :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but [LiveJS.com](http://livejs.com/) might work.

From the docs:

> Just include Live.js and it will monitor the current page including local CSS and Javascript by sending consecutive HEAD requests to the server. Changes to CSS will be applied dynamically and HTML or Javascript changes will reload the page.

Comment: This works for HTML/Javascript/CSS fine in development although it might make the browser busy sending HEAD requests. Thanks!!

Comment: Using Mac Chrome, the demo constantly refreshes and is all jumpy

Comment: @jchook Yes, LiveJs probably isn't a good option any more. What server side tech are you using? When I'm not using Meteor I use [Brunch](http://brunch.io/). Here's my [Angular Brunch Seed](https://github.com/scotch/angular-brunch-seed) Project. I believe you could also use something like [yeoman.io](http://yeoman.io/)

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want: https://github.com/viatropos/design.io

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this, but got problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468021/design-io-cant-hot-push-code